# How do you compare characters to characters in a word? (Java)

Tags: java

I'm trying to compare the character that the user enters to the randomly generated word to see if it matches or not...
what can i use to compare them?

```
    if (playerChoice.equals(g.originalWord.charAt(7))) { //
        g.revealHiddenLetter(); 
    }       
    else  {
        System.out.println(g.guessThisWord);
        guesses--;// if player is wrong they lose a guess
        System.out.println("Guesses Left: " + guesses);
    }
```

Comment: You can use the `substring` or `charAt` methods to compare characters. `substring` returns a `String` and `charAt` returns a `char`.

Comment: You can use `String.indexOf` to find the index of a letter in a String or -1 if not found.

Answer (score 1):

To compare Characters you use the == symbol not the equals() method, since in java Characters are represented as integers.So what you want to do can be achived as follows:

```
 if (playerChoice == g.originalWord.charAt(7)) { //
    g.revealHiddenLetter(); 
 }       
 else  {
     System.out.println(g.guessThisWord);
     guesses--;// if player is wrong they lose a guess
     System.out.println("Guesses Left: " + guesses);
 }
```

Comment: important to note that chars only get up-casted to integers if you evaluate them against integer types. The reason you can use `==` here is because a char is a primitive type, not because of its implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the characters in the hidden word, you could use a method such as:

```
private boolean charInWord(char playerChoice) {
    for(int i = 0; i < originalWord.length(); i++) {
            if(originalWord.charAt(i) == playerChoice) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    return false;
}
```

This will return true if the letter exists within the hidden word.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to solve this is just to convert the character to a String of length 1 and use the existing String.contains() method

```
char guess = 'h';
String originalWord = "hello";
System.out.println(originalWord.contains(Character.toString(guess)));
```